# How to skip a line in a python nested list

Tags: python, list, nested

I was trying to make a code in pyh=thon, which contain a nested list. Each list will be in a different line.

```
line1=list((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
line2=list((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
arena=list()
arena.append(line1)
arena.append('/n')
arena.append(line2)
```

However the outpoot is
`[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], '\n', [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`

How to make it to skip a line?

Comment: `print(*arena, sep='\n')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print each item of a list on a separate line by specifying the 'sep', or separator, parameter of `print()`. By default, this parameter is a space, but we can set it to '\n':

```py
line1=list((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))
line2=list((0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0))

arena=list()
arena.append(line1)
arena.append(line2)    

# Print unpacked list with separator parameter set to '\n'
print(*arena, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. And also, why didnt my code work when i appending  /n manually?

Comment: First of all, I want to point out that you were using '/n' instead of '\n' (forward slash instead of backslash), which was probably just an accident on your part. However, even if you had appended '\n' to your list, doing so probably wouldn't have given you your desired output. I tried testing this and the output was rather ugly compared to when I separated the nested lists with a newline using print(). The nested lists were indeed separated by a line, but they weren't aligned properly.

Comment: oh, got it. Have a nice day:)